# How can i format a json field in Django admin?

Tags: python, json, django, django-admin

I would like to implement a rewards system in my django project, where a user would have badges that would be displayed on their profile, and could be edited via the admin. To store these badges, instead of storing a dozen of bool field, i'm trying to use Json to store values as a list :

```py
['badge1', 'reward']
```

```py
member_badges = models.JSONField(default=list, blank=True, null=True)
```

But how can i create an entry in the admin interface that would have a list of every award available to let you pick via checkboxes the awards you want for the user, and then append these to the list ?

Thanks